# Ms-Access forms view will not display lookup table "value"

Tags: ms-access-2010

Using Ms-Access 2010 on Windows 7 - forms view will not show the lookup table value, just the number ID. The drop-down arrow is non-functional, but works fine in the table view. Table view shows the value - Georgia from States table, drop-down list works,  relationships show valid links from employee state field to the States ID. No answers posted address this peculiar problem. Any ideas?  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

On the form, do you have StateID as a text box or a combo box? To get your desired behaviour it needs to be a combo box. The properties should be set as per the attached image. Note that only one column width value is set - this means that the first column is hidden (width = 0cm) so you only see the second column. The first column needs to be there though as this is holding the value (StateID) that is being stored on the Employee table

[image: combo box properties]

Answer (score 0):

This is one of the issues with the use of Access Look-up fields stored directly in tables. They are very confusing, and worse still not supported in other database formats, so if you upscale to SQL Server or MySql you'll have to convert them all to separate tables anyway.

Create a separate table with your values in and use it as the source for your combo, and store the the StateID in your main table.

There is more of an explaination here http://access.mvps.org/access/lookupfields.htm

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem which I solved by changing the field type from Long text & Rich text to **short text**
I am inclined to think that lookup and relationship field type allows reference field type you are interested in, to be of specific type

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).